# How do I use onSelectionChange(e) to switch to another sheet in the UI? [setActiveSheet()]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have successfully used onSelectionChange(e) to update data in another sheet.
I want to also change to that sheet as the active one in the UI, but can not get it to work.
What am I missing?

This is what I have tried:

```js
function onSelectionChange(e) { 
  const cell = e.range;
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const secondSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  if(as.getName() == "Sheet1" && col == 2 && row > 12 ) {
    // This works fine, and sets the value on the Sheet2 correctly.
    secondSheet.getRange('E3').setValue(cell.getValue());
    // This does not work to change the UI to the second sheet
    e.source.setActiveSheet(secondSheet);
    // Nor this
    as.setActiveSheet(secondSheet);
  }
}
```

Is it possible to change the active sheet in the UI from within the onSelectionChange(e) function?
I have successfully used setActiveSheet in other functions to change the active sheet, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
function onSelectionChange(e) { 
  //Logger.log(e);
  const cell = e.range;
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const secondSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  if(as.getName() == "Sheet1" && col == 2 && row > 12 ) {
    secondSheet.getRange('E3').setValue(cell.getValue());
    e.source.setActiveSheet(secondSheet);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, now it does for me too. Maybe Google had an issue for the 2 hours I was working on it this morning. Really appreciate you checking!

Comment: And now it doesn't work again. Must be some apps script or sheets issue.

Comment: The onSelectionChange(e) trigger runs automatically when a user changes the selection in a spreadsheet. `To activate this trigger, you must refresh the spreadsheet once the trigger is added and every time the spreadsheet is opened.`

Comment: Yes, I also noticed that line @Cooper. There are lots of support tickets/Google Help things in for this, as it has apparently never been reliable. I am just working around it.
To future readers: Unless something changes, onSelectionChange(e) only works sometimes.

Comment: I've always found it to be reliable